# Can I Create Table in AWS Athena with SQL Alchemy ORM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, alchemy

I have been made to understand that Athena is different from normal SQL as it basically reads and queries data from an s3 backend. However, I am very much used to the SQL Alchemy ORM interface for querying databases as well as upserting data, creating tables etc. I already tried querying my company athena database with pyathena and it is working fine. However, does creating table work the same way as in other MySQL databases (such as RDS), so that I can reflect the existing tables and create a new one using my python code? Or is there some athena specific pitfall I should be aware of?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/athena/faqs/?nc=sn&loc=6

Comment: Athena is not mysql, just compatible with mysql and postgresql. Not sure what pitfalls you are referring to. Either your create table statement works or it fails with an error and Athena shiuld tell you what the error is.